# Mono ThreadPool concurrency issues

Tags: c#, mono, threadpool

I wrote one software that uses ThreadPool for multithreading.

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(128, 128);
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(512, 512);

for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
    {
        Console.Write("!");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.Write(".");
    }, null);
}
```

Inside each thread I perform blocking network operations(work with http).
Software designed around blocking network model and I cannot move to non blocking 1 threaded I/O.

It works perfect on windows platform, I can use 128-512 threads per one core without any issues, all work as it should work.
But when I moved to mono, I saw some really strange behaviour. I cannot make mono run many threads per one CPU core, max I can get - 1 thread per core, doesn't matter what I do specify in SetMinThreads/SetMaxThreads.

tried under Linux with .NET 4/4.5, MONO version 3.2.1 and some older version on my previous system.
Btw, plain threading code works well, for example this gives desired result:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
   var t = new Thread(_ => {
      Console.Write("!");
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
      Console.Write(".");
   });
   t.Start();
}
```

Comment: Of course I can reinvent the wheel and write my own shiny ThreadPool that will behave well(based on last code snippet) But it seems so wrong... What is the reason of such mono behaviour?

Comment: You should use async http requests etc.  This way you do not need many threads to handle requests.

Comment: 512 threads?! Do you realize how huge the overhead is? Why are you using so many threads, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Let me just point out that using tons of threads can be legitimate. If you've got an existing app, you don't rewrite it if avoidable. You turn up the thread dial. It is a very low-effort instrument to increase throughput. If that is enough to realize your goals, you're done in a minute.

Comment: That said, you are using thread pool auto scaling with IO bound tasks. That does not work because the thread pool does not know the right degree of parallelism. Your approach is very likely suboptimal by far.

Comment: If I do use blocking IO because I need it, I can afford this overhead of blocking IO and tons of threads, it's NOT an issue. I just need to solve this silly incompatibility issue.

Comment: >>that does not work because the thread pool does not know the right degree of parallelism>> really? then what I did with SetMinThread/SetMaxThread?

Comment: I'm basically arguing for you. You'd get better throughput by fixing the degree of parallelism to the optimal number, though. Now, you get *some* number of threads between 128 and 512.

Comment: If I needed that many threads in .NET I'd have rolled my own thread-pool anyway, just to avoid hitting a pool potentially shared with other code, so heavily.

Answer (score 7):

We've also experimented alot with mono and looks that following helps:

1. setup environment variable MONO_THREADS_PER_CPU to higher values. for example 
   export MONO_THREADS_PER_CPU=300 (linux). I'am not sure but looks that you can't tweak threadpool by setmin/max threads without "more threads per cpu" set.
2. run mono with --server switch, but it works starting from 3.2.3. here explanation http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_3.2
   , but may be this flag helps at start only when not enough threads fired.

We're using both options and mono on linux acting quite fast( comparable to .net on windows )

Comment: Where is this option set? (MONO_THREADS_PER_CPU)

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but it's environment variable, so you setting via "export" at linux and with "set" at windows.
also you could check source code(search for MONO_THREADS_PER_CPU):
https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/7eb1f72f17ab66615499e560759b5c47d9372101/mono/metadata/threadpool.c

Comment: This is the real deal - was having problems with Npgsql's async DNS name resolution, turns out it's because of a small threadpool on mono by default. Increased to (I know, too large, still tuning...) 2000 instead of the default 50, and voilà, no more problems with Npgsql or any other threadpool deadlock that I experienced earlier.

Comment: We had been seeing what we though were random timeouts across SSH, HTTPS to multiple endpoints and DB access.  This fixed our issues around timeouts soup to nuts.  Thank you we are truly in your debt.

Comment: Having done the above, we also had to set `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads` high enough on a 4 CPU/core VM. When it was low we saw the timeouts, once we moved it up, things started working again. Only on 4 CPU/core VMs though.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use a combination of these stuff (like: Asyn, MultiThreading, Parallel) if multi threading is not enough for your work !?
I think these may be helpful for you :
http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/Task-Parallel-Framework-issues-td5711359.html
stackoverflow.com/questions/5717059/implementation-of-task-in-monodroid
http://blog.errorok.com/2012/08/09/268/

Comment: I do not target any mobile platforms. I tried this code in Linux inside Virtual Box. And no, it won't add my jobs to a signle thread. It must use min/max thread settings I gave using SetMinThread/SetMaxThread and queue extra tasks for later execution. As I told code works perfect under windows, but misbehave under mono/linux.

Comment: Oh! I didn't attention the first line.
OK but what's your idea about combination of couple of techniques ?

Comment: Parallel.For doesn't work either - the same problem, everything is single threaded, while on windows it's not problem to get up to 512 threads on one core. And I need to control max threads per one task, ThreadPool seemed me the simplest solution, but for some strange reason it's bugged on mono in all versions %)

Comment: You said you're testing it on Linux inside Virtual-Box.
Are you sure that the CPU‌ properties you set, for your Linux virtual machine is ok ?

Comment: There are no any special options. I've tried with 1 and 4 cpus. If I set 4 cpus I get 4 threads, if I set 1 I get 1 thread...